# c# How to convert latitude and longitude to xy plane in enlarged map

Tags: c#, gps

I have a map which is not GOOGLE map in a picturebox. I know the width and height of the map. And I know latitude and longitude of the edges of the map image. The map image only shows small area(some buildings and streets) not the entire WORLD. What I want to do is to get xy-coordinates of the map image if I have lat&lon of some point. The point will be not out of map image.

Briefly, the main task would be conversion from lat&lon to xy coordinates if I know the edges'lat&lon.

Answer (score 0):

```
// The mapping between latitude, longitude and pixels is defined by the web
// mercator projection.
function project(latLng) {
   var siny = Math.sin(latLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180);

   // Truncating to 0.9999 effectively limits latitude to 89.189. This is
   // about a third of a tile past the edge of the world tile.
   siny = Math.min(Math.max(siny, -0.9999), 0.9999);

   return new google.maps.Point(
      TILE_SIZE * (0.5 + latLng.lng() / 360),
      TILE_SIZE * (0.5 - Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * Math.PI)));
}
```

from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates?csw=1